# How to configure everything into one or multiple configure files

Tags: json, azure-devops, azure-devops-migration-tools

I haven't used this since 2 years ago. I'm trying to figure out how to put everything into one json or it has to be mulitple jsons.

Using v11.9.46. The documentation is not clear as it references things that are for one version or another.

I'm moving items from ADOorg1 to ADOorg2. In this order I was going to setup the json

1. Areas and Iterations
2. Team setup
3. Shared Queries
4. Work Items (using a query to find select area)

This is what I had so far as I tried to figure out how to put it into one:

```
{
    "ChangeSetMappingFile": null,
    // "Endpoints": {
    //     "TfsTeamSettingsEndpoints": [
    //         {
    //             "Name": "TeamSettingsSource",
    //             "AccessToken": "",
    //             "Query": {
    //                 "Query": "SELECT [System.Id], [System.Tags] FROM WorkItems WHERE [System.TeamProject] = @TeamProject AND [System.WorkItemType] NOT IN ('Test Suite', 'Test Plan') ORDER BY [System.ChangedDate] desc"
    //             },
    //             "Organisation": "https://dev.azure.com/test1/",
    //             "Project": "test1",
    //             "ReflectedWorkItemIdField": "ReflectedWorkItemId",
    //             "AuthenticationMode": "AccessToken",
    //             "AllowCrossProjectLinking": false,
    //             "LanguageMaps": {
    //                 "AreaPath": "Area",
    //                 "IterationPath": "Iteration"
    //             }
    //         },
    //         {
    //             "Name": "TeamSettingsTarget",
    //             "AccessToken": "",
    //             "Query": {
    //                 "Query": "SELECT [System.Id], [System.Tags] FROM WorkItems WHERE [System.TeamProject] = @TeamProject AND [System.WorkItemType] NOT IN ('Test Suite', 'Test Plan') ORDER BY [System.ChangedDate] desc"
    //             },
    //             "Organisation": "https://dev.azure.com/test2/",
    //             "Project": "test2",
    //             "ReflectedWorkItemIdField": "ReflectedWorkItemId",
    //             "AuthenticationMode": "AccessToken",
    //             "AllowCrossProjectLinking": false,
    //             "LanguageMaps": {
    //                 "AreaPath": "Area",
    //                 "IterationPath": "Iteration"
    //             }
    //         }
    //     ]
    // },
    "Source": {
        "$type": "TfsTeamProjectConfig",
        "Collection": "https://dev.azure.com/test1/",
        "Project": "test1",
        "ReflectedWorkItemIDFieldName": "ReflectedWorkItemId",
        "AllowCrossProjectLinking": false,
        "AuthenticationMode": "Prompt",
        "PersonalAccessToken": "",
        "LanguageMaps": {
            "AreaPath": "Area",
            "IterationPath": "Iteration"
        }
    },
    "Target": {
        "$type": "TfsTeamProjectConfig",
        "Collection": "https://dev.azure.com/test2/",
        "Project": "Test2",
        "ReflectedWorkItemIDFieldName": "ReflectedWorkItemId",
        "AllowCrossProjectLinking": false,
        "AuthenticationMode": "Prompt",
        "PersonalAccessToken": "",
        "LanguageMaps": {
            "AreaPath": "Area",
            "IterationPath": "Iteration"
        }
    },
    "Endpoints": {
        "InMemoryWorkItemEndpoints": [
            {
                "Name": "Source",
                "EndpointEnrichers": null
            },
            {
                "Name": "Target",
                "EndpointEnrichers": null
            }
        ]
    },
    "GitRepoMapping": null,
    "LogLevel": "Information",
    "Processors": [
        {
            "$type": "TfsAreaAndIterationProcessorOptions",
            "Enabled": true,
            "PrefixProjectToNodes": false,
            "NodeBasePaths": null,
            "ProcessorEnrichers": null,
            "SourceName": "Source",
            "TargetName": "Target"
        },
        {
            "$type": "TfsTeamSettingsProcessorOptions",
            "Enabled": false,
            "MigrateTeamSettings": true,
            "UpdateTeamSettings": true,
            "PrefixProjectToNodes": false,
            "Teams": null,
            "ProcessorEnrichers": null,
            "SourceName": "Source",
            "TargetName": "Target"
        },
        {
            "$type": "WorkItemMigrationConfig",
            "Enabled": false,
            "ReplayRevisions": true,
            "PrefixProjectToNodes": false,
            "UpdateCreatedDate": true,
            "UpdateCreatedBy": true,
            "BuildFieldTable": false,
            "AppendMigrationToolSignatureFooter": false,
            "WIQLQueryBit": "AND  [Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedDate] = '' AND [System.WorkItemType] NOT IN ('Test Suite', 'Test Plan')",
            "WIQLOrderBit": "[System.ChangedDate] desc",
            "LinkMigration": true,
            "AttachmentMigration": true,
            "AttachmentWorkingPath": "E:\\temp\\WorkItemAttachmentWorkingFolder\\",
            "FixHtmlAttachmentLinks": false,
            "SkipToFinalRevisedWorkItemType": true,
            "WorkItemCreateRetryLimit": 5,
            "FilterWorkItemsThatAlreadyExistInTarget": true,
            "PauseAfterEachWorkItem": false,
            "AttachmentMaxSize": 480000000,
            "CollapseRevisions": false,
            "LinkMigrationSaveEachAsAdded": false,
            "GenerateMigrationComment": true,
            "NodeBasePaths": [
                "Product\\Area\\Path1",
                "Product\\Area\\Path2"
            ],
            "WorkItemIDs": null
        }
    ],
    "Version": "0.0",
    "workaroundForQuerySOAPBugEnabled": false,
    "WorkItemTypeDefinition": {
        "sourceWorkItemTypeName": "targetWorkItemTypeName"
    }
//     "Endpoints": {
//         "InMemoryWorkItemEndpoints": [
//             {
//                 "Name": "Source",
//                 "EndpointEnrichers": null
//             },
//             {
//                 "Name": "Target",
//                 "EndpointEnrichers": null
//             }
//         ]
//     }
}
```

Comment: Hi LordRazon, Does my answer work? Please check it and kindly let me know the result.

Answer (score 0):

If you use this [Azure DevOps Migration Tools](https://nkdagility.github.io/azure-devops-migration-tools/), it can migrate `Work Items, TestPlans & Suits, Teams, Shared Queries, & Pipelines` from one Organization to another. You could refer to Processors: [TfsAreaAndIterationProcessor](https://nkdagility.github.io/azure-devops-migration-tools/Reference/Processors/TfsAreaAndIterationProcessor.html), [TfsTeamSettingsProcessor](https://nkdagility.github.io/azure-devops-migration-tools/Reference/Processors/TfsTeamSettingsProcessor.html), [TfsSharedQueryProcessor](https://nkdagility.github.io/azure-devops-migration-tools/Reference/Processors/TfsSharedQueryProcessor.html) and [Work Item Tracking Processor](https://nkdagility.github.io/azure-devops-migration-tools/Reference/Processors/WorkItemTrackingProcessor.html) to create corresponding configuration Json files one by one.

Comment: Is there any order about which processor should run first?

Comment: Also, TfsSharedQueryProcessor does not have detail about how to setup "SourceName"&"TargetName"